# Read from multiple lines into single row until delimiter is encountered

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have been trying to read from a text file which has rows like below and has delimiter as semi-colon:

```
Sun rises
 in the east
  and;
sets in the 
west
;
```

I am trying to read the data from delimiter to delimiter in single separate records like below
  variable_name

```
1 Sun rises in the east and
2 sets in the west
```

I have tried almost all the options available with `infile` option for no avail. Is it possible to read like above? How to do it? Any clue/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post what you've tried

Comment: have tried using lrecl, linesize, @@ and all, none of them are giving the correct results, have tried so many things.

Comment: It looks like you do NOT care if multiple spaces are compressed to one? So that `'east    and'` becomes `'east and'`.  If so then just read it word by word using and stop when the word contains the delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recfm=n` is the way to tell SAS to not have 'line breaks'.  So:

```
data want;
  infile "c:\temp\test.txt" recfm=n dsd dlm=';';
  length text $1024;
  input text $;
run;
```

Note that the line break will be read as just another two characters, so if you want to remove those characters you can use `compress` with the `c` option to remove control characters (including LF/FF).

Comment: Thanks Joe.This helps. Using compress, removed the desired characters as well, I used tranward to remove "0D"x and "0A"x.

Comment: Certainly a reasonable solution.  `transtrn` is probably the best translate-variety function for that purpose but any of them will do.

Answer (score 0):

Read it word by word and concatenate into longer lines.

```
data want ;
  infile mydat end=eof  ;
  length word $200 line $2000 ;
  drop word;
  do while (^eof and ^index(word,';'));
    input word @ ;
    line = catx(' ',line,compress(word,';'));
  end;
  if _n_ > 1 or line ne ' ' then output;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom for taking your time out. This is a good hacky solution as well.